# Why does this Plug search from the beginning of the line?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to use `vim-repeat` with a `<Plug>` that camel cases text:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>CamelCase _ f_x~
\:call repeat#set("\<Plug>CamelCase")<CR>
nmap _ <Plug>CamelCase
```

This works fine for the most part, but in some cases it jumps to the beginning of the text and updates there:

```
function _noResponsesMessage(status_group) {
```

Even if I have my cursor at the beginning of `status_group`, it jumps to the beginning of the text and swaps there instead:

```
function NoResponsesMessage(status_group) {
```

Oddly, if I don't do this `<Plug>` setup and instead `nmap` it directly it works as expected:

```
nmap _ f_x~
```

Result as desired:

```
function _noResponsesMessage(statusGroup) {
```

Why does the first approach jump to the beginning of the line and the other replaces after the cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely to your Plug:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>CamelCase _ f_x~
```

You will notice that it consists of following normal mode commands:

1. `_` goto first non-blank char on the line
2. goto next char
3. and then your camelcase solution `f_x~`

Just remove it to match your nmap solution:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>CamelCase f_x~
nmap _ <Plug>CamelCase
```

I would also suggest to name Plugs in using `()`:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(CamelCase) f_x~
nmap _ <Plug>(CamelCase)
```

or `;`

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>CamelCase; f_x~
nmap _ <Plug>CamelCase;
```

Just to avoid plug name clashes.